# fill SVG stroke on scroll and remove fill on scroll up

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations, gsap

I am trying to make dashed line SVG stroke on a web page and need to fill that stroke on scroll down and on the time of scroll up again removed filled color slowly.

Below is the example website on that having scroll effect. I need the same effect.
https://asaro.co.uk/
[image]

Below is my SVG file code.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="802.354" height="3245.896" viewBox="0 0 802.354 3245.896">
```

Comment: Your `svg` contains no actual visual content, so you are asking us to design and implement your svg and also tell you how to animate it on scroll? Did you do anything more than just looking at that site and saying 'I want that, but let someone else do it'?

Comment: I have tried up with css and JavaScript in local but can't see animation effect.

Comment: Then please add all that code so we can guide you in the right direction :) Anything you tried helps us help you better!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the path twice. First time with `stroke-dasharray="8"`. The second time the `stroke-dasharray` of the use element has the same value as the path's length. I hope this is what you need.

```js
let l = Path_440.getTotalLength();
let dasharray = l;
let dashoffset = l;
theFill.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", l);
theFill.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dashoffset", l);
wrap.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  dashoffset = l - this.scrollTop * l / (this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight);
  theFill.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dashoffset", dashoffset);
});
```

```css
#wrap{height:100vh; overflow:scroll;}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 802.354 3245.896">
   <defs>
  <path id="Path_440" d="M14581.822,1364S14348,1448,14528,1848s-408,592-408,592-392,484,232,548,412,460,412,460-144,264-464,252-144,464-144,464,36,336,384,444" transform="translate(-13997.437 -1363.059)" fill="none" /></defs>
        
<use xlink:href="#Path_440" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="8"/>
   
<use id="theFill" xlink:href="#Path_440" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a solid stroke but i need to fill dark that dashed line on a scroll and also on scroll up light that dashed line default dashed line is a light color.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Please reformulate your question and try explain everything you need with examples and code